# How to sum a matrix with two other matrice as index after a max()?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two index array like these:

```
import numpy as np
p_index = np.array([2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1])
m_index = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0])
```

two object array like these:

```
p = np.array([17, 13, 16])
m = np.array([15, 14, 19])
```

and a matrix like this:

```
t=np.array([18, 16, 14, 12, 11, 19, 11, 16, 11])
```

I need to do a for-loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(t)):
    newvalue = max(p[p_index[i]],m[m_index[i]])+t[i]
    p[p_index[i]] = newvalue
    m[m_index[i]] = newvalue
```

I take array as example,but p,m,t,and the index array are all Matrix with same rows actually.I need to do this to every row.How can I do it without for-loop?

NEW↓:

If I take Matrice as example it will like these:

```
p_index = np.array([[2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])

m_index = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1]])

t=np.array([[18, 16, 14, 12, 11, 19, 11, 16, 11],
       [10, 14, 18, 17, 14, 15, 18, 19, 17],
       [18, 17, 18, 18, 10, 12, 17, 15, 14],
       [15, 15, 16, 15, 19, 12, 13, 19, 17]])

p = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

m = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

row,col = np.shape(t)
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        newvalue = max(p[i][p_index[i][j]],m[i][m_index[i][j]])+t[i][j]
        p[i][p_index[i][j]] = newvalue
        m[i][m_index[i][j]] = newvalue

f = np.max(p,axis=1).reshape(len(p),1)
```

And actually I just need the final 'f'

Comment: It looks like this is an iterative process, in which case, no, you cannot do this without a for loop.

Comment: The whole point of vectorization is to apply the same operation to chunks of data at the same time. That's not possible in an iterative process, since on each iteration you are performing a different operation.

Comment: If `p`, `m`, and `t` are matrices, can you please provide examples? There may be some minor improvements you can make, but you'll need to provide ***accurate*** example data.

Answer (score 0):

If we iterate without actually modifying `p` and `m`:

```
In [247]: for i in range(len(t)):
     ...:     print(max(p[p_index[i]],m[m_index[i]])+t[i])
     ...:     
34
33
31
31
28
35
30
32
26
```

We can get the same values with a single numpy expression:

```
In [250]: np.maximum(p[p_index], m[m_index])+t
Out[250]: array([34, 33, 31, 31, 28, 35, 30, 32, 26])
```

But with your full loop, `p` and `m` elements are modified several times, each depending on a previous iteration:

```
In [258]: for i in range(len(t)):
     ...:     newvalue = max(p[p_index[i]],m[m_index[i]])+t[i]
     ...:     print(newvalue)
     ...:     p[p_index[i]] = newvalue
     ...:     m[m_index[i]] = newvalue
     ...:     
34
33
47       # versus 31
46       
58       # versus 28
77
57
93
104

In [259]: p,m
Out[259]: (array([ 58, 104,  93]), array([104,  77,  57]))
```

There are some `numpy` tools for performing things like cumulative sums, and working with duplicate indices, but you can't (readily) apply these to general functions such as your `max(...)+t`.